# PingFederate : Could not obtain attributes from the IdP Authentication Service

Tags: liferay, single-sign-on, pingfederate

I am getting this exception while trying to invoke PingFederae `StartSSO.ping` endpoint.

```
12:49:54,153 DEBUG [IntegrationControllerServlet] GET: https://localhost:9031/idp/startSSO.ping
12:49:54,157 DEBUG [IdpAdapterSupportBase] IdP Adapter Selection disabled, performing legacy adapter selection.
12:49:54,157 DEBUG [HttpServletRespProxy] adding lazy cookie Cookie{PF=F1OpbNzE8iYqMJq6UcG5waLotsmXsBxdLFrhrm8OVFYE; path=/; maxAge=-1; domain=null} replacing Cookie{PF=F1OpbNzE8iYqMJq6UcG5wa; path=/; maxAge=-1; domain=null}
12:49:54,157 DEBUG [InterReqStateMgmtMapImpl] setAttr(oldKey: null, newKey: LotsmXsBxdLFrhrm8OVFYE, name: NUMBER_OF_ATTEMPTS, value: 1)
12:49:54,157 DEBUG [HttpServletRespProxy] flush cookies: adding Cookie{PF=F1OpbNzE8iYqMJq6UcG5waLotsmXsBxdLFrhrm8OVFYE; path=/; maxAge=-1; domain=null}
12:49:54,160 DEBUG [BindingServiceImpl] Not transporting protocol response message because the HTTP response has been committed (this is a normal condition usually due to an adapter or other component redirecting the user or writing its own content to the response). 
12:49:54,232 DEBUG [IntegrationControllerServlet] GET: https://localhost:9031/idp/ENvrS/resumeSAML20/idp/startSSO.ping
12:49:54,233 DEBUG [IdpAdapterSupportBase] IdP Adapter Selection disabled, performing legacy adapter selection.
12:49:54,233 DEBUG [InterReqStateMgmtMapImpl] getAttr(key: LotsmXsBxdLFrhrm8OVFYE, name: NUMBER_OF_ATTEMPTS): 1
12:49:54,233 DEBUG [HttpServletRespProxy] adding lazy cookie Cookie{PF=F1OpbNzE8iYqMJq6UcG5waTbQaafveigalePVvdwcdta; path=/; maxAge=-1; domain=null} replacing null
12:49:54,233 DEBUG [InterReqStateMgmtMapImpl] setAttr(oldKey: LotsmXsBxdLFrhrm8OVFYE, newKey: TbQaafveigalePVvdwcdta, name: NUMBER_OF_ATTEMPTS, value: 2)
12:49:54,233 DEBUG [InterReqStateMgmtMapImpl] Object removeAttr(key: TbQaafveigalePVvdwcdta, name: NUMBER_OF_ATTEMPTS): 2
12:49:54,233 DEBUG [TrackingIdSupport] [cross-reference-message] entityid:sbwb-ppc-idp subject:null
12:49:54,233 ERROR [HandleAuthnRequest] Exception occurred during request processing
org.sourceid.websso.profiles.RequestProcessingException: Unexpected Runtime Authn Adapter Integration Problem.
    at org.sourceid.websso.profiles.ResumableRequestHandlerBase.resume(ResumableRequestHandlerBase.java:54)
    at org.sourceid.websso.profiles.ResumableRequestHandlerBase.resume(ResumableRequestHandlerBase.java:78)
    at org.sourceid.saml20.profiles.ProfileProcessManager.resumeHandleRequest(ProfileProcessManager.java:73)
    at $ProfileProcessMgmtService_1461cd08008.resumeHandleRequest($ProfileProcessMgmtService_1461cd08008.java)
    at org.sourceid.websso.servlet.IntegrationControllerServlet.process(IntegrationControllerServlet.java:63)
    at org.sourceid.websso.servlet.EnforcerServletBase.checkProcess(EnforcerServletBase.java:89)
    at org.sourceid.websso.servlet.EnforcerServletBase.doGet(EnforcerServletBase.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1448)
    at org.sourceid.servlet.filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:55)
    at org.sourceid.servlet.filter.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.sourceid.websso.servlet.ProxyFilter.doFilter(ProxyFilter.java:34)
    at org.sourceid.servlet.filter.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:994)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.handle(SslConnection.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.sourceid.saml20.adapter.AuthnAdapterException: org.sourceid.saml20.adapter.AuthnAdapterException: Could not obtain attributes from the IdP Authentication Service.
    at org.sourceid.saml20.profiles.idp.IdpAdapterSupportBase.lookupAuthN(IdpAdapterSupportBase.java:141)
    at org.sourceid.saml20.profiles.idp.HandleAuthnRequest.doResume(HandleAuthnRequest.java:245)
    at org.sourceid.saml20.profiles.ResumableRequestHandlerBase.exeResume(ResumableRequestHandlerBase.java:66)
    at org.sourceid.websso.profiles.ResumableRequestHandlerBase.resume(ResumableRequestHandlerBase.java:50)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.sourceid.saml20.adapter.AuthnAdapterException: Could not obtain attributes from the IdP Authentication Service.
    at com.pingidentity.adapters.opentoken.IdpAuthnAdapter.lookupAuthNHelper(IdpAuthnAdapter.java:159)
    at com.pingidentity.adapters.opentoken.IdpAuthnAdapter.lookupAuthN(IdpAuthnAdapter.java:78)
    at org.sourceid.websso.authn.AdapterAuthnProcessor.lookupAuthN(AdapterAuthnProcessor.java:96)
    at org.sourceid.saml20.profiles.idp.IdpAdapterSupportBase.lookupAuthN(IdpAdapterSupportBase.java:132)
    ... 46 more
12:49:54,238 DEBUG [HttpServletRespProxy] flush cookies: adding Cookie{PF=F1OpbNzE8iYqMJq6UcG5waTbQaafveigalePVvdwcdta; path=/; maxAge=-1; domain=null}
12:49:54,239 DEBUG [BindingServiceImpl] Not transporting protocol response message because the HTTP response has been committed (this is a normal condition usually due to an adapter or other component redirecting the user or writing its own content to the response).
```

And i think this exception is invoked when the PingFederate cannot find the OpenToken generated by application. But the cookie is present in the browser. 
[image: OpenToken Cookie]

And the Ping Federate Application shows the error page :

[image]

And my Idp Adapter setting looks like :

```
cookie-path=/
use-verbose-error-messages=false
cipher-suite=2
obfuscate-password=true
session-cookie=false
password=Kyx+ElfeRRDkPRYZoVF3BQ==
token-name=opentoken
cookie-domain=.banka.liferay.com
token-notbefore-tolerance=0
token-renewuntil=43200
use-sunjce=false
secure-cookie=false
token-lifetime=300
use-cookie=true
```

I am struggling to find out the cause of this problem. But with no success.

What could be the cause of this problem? Is it related to Ping Federate or am i missing something in my configuration ?

And here is the Screen-shot of IdP Adapter :

[image: Idp Adapter]

And here is the summary of SP Connection :

[image: SP Connection1]
[image: Sp Connection2]
[image: SP Conenction3]
[image: SP Connection4]

Comment: This is generally an issue with the IdP adapter that you have assigned. I don't see in the log that even redirects to the adapter at all. Did you DIY your IdP adapter, or modify/use one of ours?

Comment: No, i did it myself. But however i had used the default server setting as provided .

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your IdP Adapter Summary Screen, as well as your Connection Summary Screen?

Comment: @AndyK.-PingIdentity i have added the screenshot of the IdP adapter and the SP connection summary.

Comment: So, when you go to /idp/StartSSO.ping?partner=..., do you get properly redirected to your authentication service at banka.liferay.com:8080?

Comment: Yes i do get properly redirected to banka.liferay.com:8080 and through there i again redirect to the <ping-federeate-server>/resume URL ...

Comment: Last question... I hope! Can you paste the actual text of the opentoken cookie in, please? Not just an image?

Comment: Here is the Content of cookie : `T1RLAQLE29CYKQCqEn5V9Ih4hjg1UAL5FxD8wpejuXasaDHaWC9aq8vdAACgg_y5insv4_mZk5AHiJW-qIYp0ODiU1pZ2tHylc9V5-fWslFGVZ7SG1Kfez7faK8XRDJTMm6ciEDowCf2NnXlm0I4mKOsPbXAZch9hiSLrEll_FYqdiHQS_i7EIlago4QYIGZ8hhhb8WKyLXJC6uiT7QOvq_RiPBLShhp7HvRpP4KyyBeM12YP_aPJX6mzLlVv11vor7xO2s8EzGXohW73w**`

Comment: And a quick question , do we need to set openToken when the endpoint /startSSO.ping is invoked or when PF redirects to authentication service ? just clearing my thoughts i have tried both ..

Comment: The opentoken decodes properly. :-/  So, stepping through... You redirect for authn, you get an opentoken at authn, and it decodes properly, based on the settings you provided... Are you using the Java integration kit, or just the reference adapter?

Comment: At first let me revisit you to my steps ... A user login to IdP Application which redirects to StartSSO.ping , then PF IdP server redirects to authentication service ... And then again from authentication service the resume URL is called ... Is this the correct flow ?

Comment: And yes i have used Java integration kit, provided Open Token adapter.

Comment: that's the correct flow... As you return to the resume, PingFed should decrypt the token, consume the attributes, and then redirect you on to the SP side...

Comment: hey @AndyK.-PingIdentity thanks for listening my , queries . And i found a similar kind of error handling technique in the Ping Federate Forum https://www.pingidentity.com/support/solutions/index.cfm/Troubleshooting-Page-Expired-Error .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be that you're redirected to the resume URL with the hostname being localhost? In that case your browser won't send a cookie issued to .banka.liferay.com to the server, hence the error.

Comment: I didn't get what you are implying on. OK here is the flow after login through `banka.liferay.com`, `https://localhost:9031/idp/startSSO.ping` is invoked through redirection.After which `banka.liferay.com/web/my-bank/home?resume=/idp/bUDlM/resumeSAML20/idp/startSSO.ping&spentity=sbwb-ppc-idp` , then it is redirected to pingFederate server location `https://localhost:9031/idp/bUDlM/resumeSAML20/idp/startSSO.ping` . Isn't this the supposed flow of redirection ?
  is executed

Comment: What I meant is that your browser won't send a cookie set for .banka.liferay.com to localhost. You'll either want to change the Base URL of PingFederate so that it's on the same cookie domain as the application, or you can opt to send the OpenToken as a query parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think i will try using query parameter for now. If it works i can indeed correct the mistake in my cookie based method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. At-least i got rid of the error log as issued above. Not a way i want it to be, a OpenToken as query parameter , but i will figure out the way to handle cookie.

Comment: Good call, Mehmet! Completely missed that. [sigh] Forest from the trees, and all that.